# How do I include and submit a form using Impromptu dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, form-submit, impromptu

What is the proper way to include and submit a form to a PHP page via jquery impromptu.

Currently, I'm doing:

```
<script>
  var someform = '<form method="post" action="my.php" id="myform">
  Enter your name<br />
  <input name="name" /><br />
  What's your favorite color?<br />
  <select name="color">
    <option>red></option>
    <option>blue</option>
  </select><br />
  Tell us more about that<br />
  <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="submit" />
  </form>';

  function callback_form(v,m,f){

    if(v == 1)
    {
  $('#myform').submit();
      location.reload();
    }
    else
    {
      $.prompt.close()
    }
  }
</script>
```

In the html, when I call it, the form displays and refreshes the page, but doesn't submit.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.prompt(someform,{ callback: callback_form, buttons: { Cancel: 0, Add: 1 },focus: 1 });">Launch Form</a>
```

I feel like there's gotta be some easy mistake I'm making, but I can't find any examples of someone actually including form tags using impromptu. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Can anyone help me with the best method of prompting for user input and actually submitting the form using impromptu?

Answer (score 1):

That is, beause you are reloading the page while you are submiting. If you submit the form, your page will go to the 'my.php', so you do not need the 'location.reload()'.

Comment: `s/do not need/should not have/`

Comment: If I remove the reload line, the page doesn't appear to work at all. The dialog box closes but the page doesn't behave as if I had clicked a submit button. I wonder if I need to have an undisplayed button that I use jquery to physically "click"?

Comment: Update: if I put <input type="submit"> in the actual form and click the button, it submits fine. So the $('#myform').submit(); action is behaving differently than actually clicking a submit button, when I would think the behavior would be the same.

Comment: I figured it out; thanks for the help!

Apparently, I needed to change $.prompt(someform,{ callback: callback_form to $.prompt(someform,{ submit: callback_form ). When I referenced the submission behavior instead of calling the function, everything worked just as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to submit the form via ajax like this:

```
$.post('my.php',f,function(data,status,xhr){
    //do something here
});
```

Comment: Okay, can you rephrase that in the context of the form example above? Sorry, I've never used $.post before...

Comment: @user882134, this works fine, though my.php doesn't exist, it is posting the right stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/vPuFe/

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; thanks for the help!

Apparently, I needed to change callback to submit

```
$.prompt(someform,{ callback: callback_form
```

to 
    `$.prompt(someform,{ submit: callback_form` ). When I referenced the submission behavior instead of calling the function, everything worked just as it should.